# Why aren't my commandline arguments being read?

Tags: c++, command, arguments

I am calling this in my program:

```
std::string gameDirectory = "";
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] == "-game")
            gameDirectory = argv[i + 1];
    }

    if (gameDirectory == "")
        exit(0);
```

With the commandline argument

```
-game demo
```

and it refuses to set the gameDirectory. Any ideas?

Comment: Define "it refuses to set". What actually does happen? And how does it differ from what you want to happen? And how did you determine both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[i]` is of type `const char*`, and direct comparison of pointers return true only if they point to the same location. Program arguments will never point to the same location as existing constant strings, so the `if` is never visited.

You either need to make either string a `std::string` (which has == overloads for comparing with char pointers), or use `strcmp` to compare the arguments instead.

```
if (strcmp(argv[i], "-game") == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Turn on your compilation warnings!!!**

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
> main.cpp:8:24: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]
>          if (argv[i] == "-game")
>                         ^
> ```

This warning tells you everything you need to know ([live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83ffaee299b5ff00)).

Use `strcmp` to compare C-strings.

Comment: Hmm, my compiler warnings are on but I'm not getting that. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @Boncey: They're not on _enough_! :)